# Error inserting dates into my SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, date, insert, sql-insert, sql-date-functions

I have a table called `TPatientVisits` and when I try to insert dates I'm getting this error. I'm not quite sure why the error is there I'm pretty sure that my date is formatted correctly because I use the same format in different tables and they work.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 292
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Below is my inserts for the table can anyone tell me why this isn't working

```
INSERT INTO TPatientVisits (intPatientID, dtmVisit, intVisitTypeID, intWithdrawReasonID)
VALUES (1, '01/01/2017', 1, null),
       (1, '01/02/2017', 2, null),
       (1, '01/03/2017', 3, 3),
       (2, '02/02/2017', 1, null),
       (2, '02/03/2017', 2, null),
       (2, '02/04/2017', 3, 2),
       (3, '08/14/2017', 1, null),
       (3, '08//15/2017',  2, null),
       (3, '08//16/2017', 3, 6),
       (4, '12/12/2017', 1, null),
       (4, '12/13/2017', 2, null),
       (4, '12/14/2017', 3, 1),
       (5, '01/06/2017', 1, null),
       (5, '01/07/2017', 2, null),
       (5, '01/08/2017', 3, 5),
       (6, '06/06/2017', 1, null),
       (6, '06/07/2017', 2, null),
       (6, '06/08/2017', 3, 6),
       (7, '11/15/2017', 1, null),
       (7, '11/16/2017', 2, null),
       (7, '11/17/2017', 3, 2),
       (8, '11/16/2017', 1, null),
       (8, '11/17/2017', 2, null),
       (8, '11/18/2017', 3, 5),
       (9, '03/03/2017', 1, null),
       (9, '03/04/2017', 2, null),
       (9, '03/05/2017', 3, 4),
       (10, '08/08/2017', 1, null),
       (10, '08/09/2017', 2, null),
       (10, '08/10/2017', 3, 5)
```

Comment: Looks like SQL Server. Format dates as `'20170808'` (YYYYMMDD) ISO-8601 format is culture independent

Comment: You have double `//` for these dates... `,( 3, '08//15/2017',  2, null )
        ,( 3, '08//16/2017', 3, 6 )`

Answer (score 0):

Wei is correct above (+1'd) in that inserting values into a date column means the values must be compatible with date format, and '08//15/2017' and '08//16/2017' are not.

So you'll have to go through your hard-coded VALUES list and ensure all dates are dates.  If these values were SELECTed from a table then using TRY_CAST or ISDATE() would work, although I've heard that ISDATE() includes some false positives.